# Unable to install chaincode on hyperledger fabric based peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I tried below command

```
echo -e "Installing chaincode on peer2 of org2 now....\n"
docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP \
    -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer2.org2.example.com:7051 \
    -e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer2.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt \
    -e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer2.org2.example.com/tls/server.key \
    -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer2.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
    -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp \
    cli peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
```

I am getting following error. I could install chaincode on all other peers successfully.

```
2022-01-27 13:13:33.744 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> WARN 121 Failed to invoke chaincode channel= chaincode=_lifecycle error="error in simulation: failed to execute transaction cfe6ea05af60787c665900fd685a5f037098a3adb3137f3a48db6b0e643ae440: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction"
2022-01-27 13:13:33.744 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 122 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.7:59556 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5m0.004667347s
2022-01-27 13:23:28.627 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 123 Received block [9] from buffer channel=channelone
2022-01-27 13:23:28.631 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 124 [channelone] Validated block [9] in 3ms
2022-01-27 13:23:28.667 UTC [kvledger] CommitLegacy -> INFO 125 [channelone] Committed block [9] with 1 transaction(s) in 29ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=5ms state_commit=1ms) commitHash=[ce41d01661edff937d020d18a8facadd67a94368773f1ab31db92bbd4ff54026]
2022-01-27 13:34:57.933 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 126 finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 300001ms channel= txID=9d859382
2022-01-27 13:34:57.934 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 127 failed to invoke chaincode _lifecycle, error: timeout expired while executing transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:1181
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).execute
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:272
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
```

Comment: Please provide channel configuration and any additional details you can provide.

Comment: Hi, I could install on all the peers now and I did not make any change in the configuration files of peers, orderers and channel settings. I attempted to create a network of fabric with two orgs, two peers in each org, one orderer and deployed chaincode on all peers. Later I wanted to add new peers to the existing setup which is in the running state and in the process while trying to install chaincode on newly added peers I encountered issue with one peer. However, it got resolved on its own when wifi network settings are refreshed and repeated the same experiment second time.

Comment: Ok. You should now close the question, or if you know you can post the answers (after two days of posting this question).